# Sqlite select query to return two columns value if the one condition is met

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I have table with data in the format

```
+---+-------+----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
|id | name1 |   date1  |  name2  |   date2  | name3 |   date3  |
+---+-------+----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| 1 | Jack  | 02.03.13 | Michael | 07.12.10 | Clare | 08.15.99 |
+---+-------+----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
```

The purpose of the Select query I am trying to make it to return the value of the "nameX" column if the "dateX" condition is met while X refers to same number.

```
Select nameX, dateX FROM tableName WHERE dateX = "08.15.99"
```

I am not sure how to make that X as variable as the date condition can fall at any column and it has to return its connected name column value

Comment: Is the number of name/date column sets known and unchanging? In your example, it is 3.

Comment: @nofinator yes they are known and unchanging. they will always be name1, date1...... The example date I gave is example value I will pass to search for in the columns

Comment: Your table is an example of bad database design. What currently is 7 columns and one row should be 3 columns (id, name, date) and 3 rows. Consider changing the way you build your database, instead of trying to work around design issues with SQL hacks.

Comment: @Tomalak I thought same. But this data is going to be for one user. Each user will have a list of names and dates linked with his/her profile. Imaging that id a profile name not a number, any suggestions what would be the best database format in this case?

Comment: Is there a case that more than 1 of date1, date2 and date3 have the same value in the same row?

Comment: @forpas No, always different.

Comment: The way I understand it from your descriptions: table `users` (user_id, any, other, fixed, metadata) and table `username` (user_id, name, date). And then an INNER JOINs between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE '08.15.99'
         WHEN date1 THEN name1
         WHEN date2 THEN name2
         WHEN date3 THEN name3
       END nameX,
       '08.15.99' dateX
FROM tablename
WHERE '08.15.99' IN (date1, date2, date3);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e447a10ca320965be67156553d19bf6f).

Comment: Note that this combines rows when two or more dates on the same record are 08.15.99.  This may be OK or not...

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I already asked for this in the comments under the question and the OP clarified that there is no case that 2 dates are equal in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Select Name1  AS Name,Date1 AS Date From tableName Where date1="08.15.99"
    UNION ALL
    Select Name2,Date2 From tableName Where date2="08.15.99"
    UNION ALL
    Select Name3,Date3 From tableName Where date3="08.15.99"
```

Your data source is unnormalized, making it awkward to deal with.  If you have control over it you should rewrite it in normal form; one row per name-date pair.